# What does "!" before a function do in D

Tags: d

I'm trying to learn some D for a project and frequently see code such as

```
    foreach (i; 0 .. 10)
        benchmark!test(1)[0]
            .to!("msecs", double)
            .reverseArgs!writefln
                (" took: %.2f miliseconds");
```

I'm uncertain on why some function calls have ! before them while others do not.

Comment: !symbol is a short form of !(symbol) which is a template argument, in other languages you might find this like func<symbol>

Comment: Note that in this case you don't even need reverse Args: `test(1)[0].to!("msecs", double).writefln!" took: %.2f miliseconds";` works too.

Comment: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates.html Go all the way down to “Summary” for a quick overview.

Answer (score 8):

Well, `!` BEFORE a function inverts the result, just like `if(!a)`. But `!` AFTER a function separates it from its compile-time (template) arguments, like `to!int`. The parenthesis on those arguments are optional iff it is one simple word, so like `benchmark!test` or `to!int`, but if it is more than that, it needs parens like `to!("msecs", double)`.

In a lot of cases, a function is passed like `reverseArgs!writefln` which just passed the `writefln` function as a compile-time argument to the `reverseArgs` template/function.

So in general: `foo!(compile, time, args)(run, time, args)` where not all functions have `!(compile, time args)`.

Does that make sense? I can try to edit if not...

Comment: Thanks very much that clarifies a lot.